# Slideshare/Linkedin API HTTP 403 response

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

are these api calls disabled for slideshare?

we are getting a HTTP 403 forbidden response.

get_user_campaigns

get_user_leads

get_user_campaign_leads

The API call point I was trying to use was https://www.slideshare.net/api/v4/lead-campaigns and I am using the GET Method with Parameter of Api key, ts, hash, username, password and access token

I have use access token from Linkedin API. ts is timestamp and hash is combined api secret and ts combine in SHA1

API key and secret was provided by slideshare.

Then I proceeded using PHP Curl and It kept returning 403 forbidden. What I have done wrong. Can you help me?

All other api call for searching, uploading and deleting slide is working fine.